# Bigquery - How to abstract repeated logic

Tags: google-bigquery

I find myself in a situation where I would repeat the same logic over and over like this

```
SELECT
  city,
  CAST(SUM(IF(date > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY), value, 0)) AS INT64) AS value_7,
  CAST(SUM(IF(date > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 14 DAY), value, 0)) AS INT64) AS value_14
FROM
  table
GROUP BY
  city
```

now next to `value` I have 10 other columns to which I want to apply the same logic. is there an easy way to abstract the formatting and conditioning away?

like `my_func(val_col, date_col, days)`?

I know I can do it manually, but it looks so ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is true that "BigQuery doesn't support defining aggregated function on your own" (hopefully yet) - there is always workaround - see below (for BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION my_func(arr ARRAY<STRUCT<date_col DATE, val_col INT64>>, days INT64) AS ((
  SELECT CAST(SUM(IF(date_col > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL days DAY), val_col, 0)) AS INT64)
  FROM UNNEST(arr)
)); 
SELECT
  city,
  my_func(ARRAY_AGG((date, value)), 7) value_7,
  my_func(ARRAY_AGG((date, value)), 14) value_14
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY city
```

so if you need to repeat same logic for let's say another column - value2  - you just add below to above query (and so on ...)

```
  my_func(ARRAY_AGG((date, value2)), 7) value2_7,
  my_func(ARRAY_AGG((date, value2)), 14) value2_14
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. Thx for the help.